# Copy the value of one column to another column of different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to create a select where in the second_value column, the value of the first_value column is copied when the type is 'B'

In other words, place the same value in the column: first_value in the second_value column only when the type is 'B'.
Type 'C' does not put anything in the second value column.
Example

```
id  descripcion   type   first_value    second_value
1   grain          A     1000   
2   beans          B                    1000 (copied from the first_value column)
3   sugar          C     2000
```

I'm trying something like this but I have not obtained the desired result

```
 SELECT id, description, type, firt_value, 
     CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN first_value end second_value
```

Is it possible to do this? And how would I do it?

Comment: how do below answers work for you?

Comment: Copied from where?  Your description only talks about one row of data, but your example has two.  Somehow I think they are both involved.

Comment: Apologies if I have not been clear enough, I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you were almost there. You only need another `CASE ... END` nulling `first_value` when the type is `'B'`.

```
SELECT id,
       description,
       type,
       CASE
         WHEN type = 'B'
           THEN NULL
         ELSE
           first_value
       END first_value,
       CASE
         WHEN type = 'B'
           THEN first_value
         ELSE
           second_value
       END second_value;
```

Comment: It does not work for me because it places the value in the first row, where the type is 'A', I need it to be in the second row where the type is 'B'

Comment: @bryannsi: I edited my answer. Hopefully getting right what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, description, type,  
    CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN first_value ELSE null end first_value,
CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN first_value ELSE null end second_value
```

Comment: Do this to get them on same line

Answer (score 0):

You would need `case` expression with `subquery` to get the previous row :

```
select *, (case when type = 'B'
                then (select top 1 t1.first_value 
                      from table t1
                      where t1.id < t.id
                      order by t1.id desc
                     ) else first_value
           end) as second_value
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Else condition to your query

```
SELECT id, description, type,
CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN first_value
 Else null end as first_value
 CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN first_value
 Else second_value end as second_value
```